# Bootstrap carousel START on hover

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, carousel

Is there anyway to have a bootstrap carousel start on mouse over, and then stop (goes back to original start image) when no longer hovered? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I am not having carousel on my machine to test with, but with the following tips you're supposed to cope this task:

From my sources given at end, with
[[1]](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel-examples) you can see how to run or stop carousel with following codes:

```
.carousel('cycle')  // Start cycling.

.carousel('pause')  // Stop cycling.

.carousel(0)   // go to slide 0 (AFAIK it is where you start, equivalent to start over)
```

These you should run from the mouseover [[2]](http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/) and mouseleave [[3]](http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/) event handlers.

That's it folks ;)

---

**My sources:**

[1] http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel-examples 
[2] http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/ 
[3] http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/